# getting the browser original width and height even in browser restore mode

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently creating an image modal. Here is my screenshot below

[image]

Everything is working fine but my problem starts when I tried to re size my browser. Every time I adjust the size of my browser it changes the size too. Is it possible to get the client's screen size? even if that client is in restore mode. All I want is the maximum value's for client's screen so I can work it with well. Regards. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you want to adjust your design so it will only work if the user maximises their browser window. Don't do that. Work with the window size they are using for the site.

Comment: No. I wanted like what Facebook does. Its image modal doesn't change its size even if you clicked the image with small browser size

Comment: That isn't how Facebook works. While it has a (fairly small) minimum size, it *does* scale to fit the window at larger sizes.

Answer (score 2):

use `window.screen` to get client screen size

```
window.screen.availWidth and window.screen.availHeight
```